# Concat buffer serialport

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, buffer

Hello I try to concatenate the buffer of a serial port (rflink)

```
myport.on('data', (data) => {
 console.log(data)})
```

I receive

```
<Buffer 32 30>
<Buffer 3b 30 30 3b 4e 6f 64 6f 20 52 61 64 69 6f 46 72 65 71 75 65 6e 63 79 4c>
<Buffer 69 6e 6b 20 2d 20 52 46 4c 69 6e 6b 20 47 61 74 65 77 61 79 20 56 31 2e>
<Buffer 31 20 2d 20 52 34 38 3b 0d 0a>
```

or I wish to have 1 lines and not N lines

I've been trying

```
var receiveData = '';
myport. on (' data', (data) => {
receiveData += data
console.log(receiveData)}
```

I receive

```
20;00;Nodo RadioFr
20;00;Nodo RadioFrequencyLink - RFLink Gat
20;00;Nodo RadioFrequencyLink - RFLink Gateway V1.1 - R48;
```

My serial port is configured as follows

```
myport = new serialport(com, {
          baudRate: 57600,
          databits: 8,
          parity: 'none',
          stopBits: 1,
          buffersize : 4096,
          flowControl: false,
          parser: new serialport.parsers.Readline('\n\r')
```

I just want receive

```
20;00;Nodo RadioFrequencyLink - RFLink Gateway V1.1 - R48;
```

Can someone help me out ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error, you have to use a parser:

```
 const serialport = require('serialport');
 const Readline = serialport.parsers.Readline;
 const parser = new Readline();

 myport.pipe(parser);
 parser.on('data', (data) => {
 console.log(data)})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it like this

`console.log(data.toString())`

read more bout buffer objects